saving secrets with nuke-build not working
I have a secret parameter added to nuke
//Azure Web App Deployment 
[Parameter] readonly string DeploymentUsername;
[Parameter, Secret] readonly string DeploymentPassword;
[Parameter] readonly string KuduApiUrl;

I have installed nuke both locally & globally.. and everytime I run nuke :secrets or dotnet nuke secret, I keep getting a response
There are no parameters marked with SecretAttribute

Any initial/basic step I am missing ??
Gone through documentation, seems like no additional step is required https://nuke.build/docs/global-tool/secrets/

does nuke-build asks for the password & secret value only if one invokes a task?
